# GPS enabling Android

Tags: android, gps

I try to connect Location service without using Location setting but any time I have run the project it gives error. I mentioned the code below

```
public class Practice2  extends Activity implements LocationListener{
private static final String TAG = "Profile";
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;



protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.practice2);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("Latitude","status");
}}
```

Please let me with a sample coding how I can Enable location service without navigating to location service.

These are my written logcat

```
04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Test/com.example.Test.Practice2}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Test.Practice2 cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Test.Practice2 cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at 
com.example.Test.Practice2.onCreate(Practice2.java:45)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)


04-04 06:48:35.537: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will need to implements LocationListener as you are casting this to LocationListener.

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  
(android.location.LocationListener) this);

Comment: Provide full code of this file.

Comment: I did all these but again same errors,

Comment: i added the whole code please check and let me know thanks again

Comment: Have you added Location permission "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" or "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" for application in AndroidManifest.xml ???

Comment: yes I did it as well

Comment: Make sure that you haven't confused `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` and `android.location.LocationListener`. If you accidentally implement the first one and try to cast to the second one there's of course a ´ClassCastException´. Which one(s) have you imported?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your source code, It is working Fine.

You can also refer Source :

[Location - developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates)

[LocationUpdates - developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates)

[Sample of location update from developer.android.com](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java)

[BasicLocationSample from developer.android.com](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/BasicLocationSample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/basiclocationsample/MainActivity.java)